# Not able to execute any oledb commands

Tags: vb.net

Im doing a project on examination seating arrangement using vb.net and access.
But then im not to perform any of the queries like inserting or retrieving.Whenever i try to do that im getting an error saying method or operation not implemented.Here is my code....

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class form4
    'global declarations'
    Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Exam.accdb"
    Dim conn As New OleDbconnection(constring)
    Dim adapter As OleDbdataadapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    'inserting into db'
    Private Sub add()

        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Tclassroom(Room no,Capacity) VALUES(@Room,@Capacity)"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@Room", TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@Capacity", TextBox3.Text)
        Try
            If cmd.executenonquery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Successfully inserted")
                retrieve()
                cleartxt()
            End If
            conn.close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

thnkzz in advance...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MtxT.jpg)

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  The complete error needs to be *in the post*; dont make us go somewhere else just to understand what you are trying to ask...that image is way too small for some to read. thnkzz

Comment: If you have a field with a space like Room No then you need to enclose it in square brackets to avoid confusing the sql parser of your database [Room No]

Comment: Your image is too small to be read properly.  It looks like you just created a class called `OleDbCommand`, but why?  That class already exists in the `System.Data.OleDb` namespace and it's not clear why you are not using the existing class.  i would say to get rid of that class and use the built in class